# Find startup's industry from its description

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using AngelList DB to categorize startups based on their industries since these startups are categorized based on community input which is misleading most of the time.

My business objective is to extract keywords that indicate to which industry this specific startup belongs to then map it to one of the industries specified in LinkedIn sheet https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/industry-codes

I experimented with Azure Machine learning, where I pushed 300 startups descriptions and analyzed the keyword extraction was pretty bad and was not even close to what I am trying to achieve.

I would like to know how data scientists will approach this problem? where should I look? and where I should not? is keyword analysis tools (like Google Adwords keyword planner is a viable option)

Comment: Can you clarify what you're aiming for with a full example?

Comment: Algorithm for clustering startups: http://blog.funderbeam.com/5-competitive-startup-clustering-skills/

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55138/755

Comment: @D.W. I deleted the duplicate, I thought it is more relevant there. thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2):

Using Text Classification...

To be able to treat this as a *classification* problem, you need a training set, which is a set of AngelList entries that are labeled with correct LinkedIn categories. This can be done manually, or you can hire some [Mechanical Turks](https://www.mturk.com/) to do the job for you.

Since you have ~150 categories, I'd imagine you need at least 20-30* AngelList entries for each of them. So your training set will be  {input: angellist_description, result: linkedin_id}

After that, you need to dig through text classification techniques to try and optimize the accuracy/precision of your results. The book "Taming Text" has a full chapter on text classification. And a good tool to implement a text-based classifier would be Apache Solr or Apache Lucene.

** 20-30 is a quick personal estimate and not based on a scientific method. You can look up some methods online for a good estimation method.*

Answer (score 0):

Using Text Clustering.

**Step #1** 
Use text clustering to extract main 'topics' from all the descriptions. *([Carrot2](http://project.carrot2.org/download.html) can be helpful here)*

1. Input corpus of all descriptions
2. Process: Text Clustering using Carrot2
3. Output each document will be labeled with a topic

**Step #2**
Manually map the extracted topics into LinkedIn's categories.

**Step #3**
Use the output of the first two steps to traverse from *company* -> *extracted topic* -> *linkedin category*